# In a class constructor, define a vector of T type

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, vector

I can already define a function pointer vector with a fixed parameter type in the `public:` header, then update it in the constructor. But, if I want to be able to pass a function pointer vector with a parameter of any type, how can I define it before the constructor updates it?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class foo {
public:
    std::vector<void (*)(int)> functions;

    foo(std::vector<void (*)(int)> x) {
        functions=x;
    }

    void run() {
        functions[0](2);
    }
};

void square(int n) { std::cout << n*n; }

int main() {
    foo* bar=new foo(std::vector<void (*)(int)>{square});
    bar->run();
    return 0;
}
```

Now, how could I pass a vector to the constructor with any type?

```
//snippet from above
std::vector<void (*)()> functions; //what do i do here?

template <typename T>   
foo(std::vector<void (*)(T)> x) { //this works fine
    functions=x;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can turn the class into a class template instead

```
template<class T>
class foo {
public:
    std::vector<void (*)(T)> functions;
    foo(std::vector<void (*)(T)> x) : functions(x)
    { }
    ...
}

foo<int>* bar=new foo(std::vector<void (*)(int)>{square});
```

I would also recommend switching from a function pointer to [std::function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) and that you don't use raw pointers. Use [std::unique_ptr](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) or one of its cousins.

Comment: Ah, thanks, works now. Will look into making those other changes.

Comment: Note that you can easily have `foo` of any number of parameters by changing `<class T>` to `<class... T>`